# Programmatic access to the Word/XLS/PPT Accessibility Checker

Tags: accessibility

I am working on a web application that takes MS documents(word, excel, ppt) as input documents and generates PDF documents, while it's possible to create the accessible PDF using the API/library that I am currently using, I was looking for an API/Library that will help me scan the input document(word, ppt, excel) for accessibility compliance.

As if the input document itself is lacking the semantic meta-data for accessibility the resulting PDF will not be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word itself has a scripting interface for VBscript (Windows/Mac) and AppleScript (Mac only). Not sure how far you can get with those, but I seem to remember that they both expose a lot of stuff about Word documents, so this is a possible pathway.

libreoffice has a python scripting interface - this may be another viable approach.

There are certainly command-line tools which can manipulate word files in various ways. Try this post:

[Creating & Editing MS-Word documents on a linux server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721682/creating-editing-ms-word-documents-on-a-linux-server)

Comment: thank you for reply, but I want to check document for accessibility issues from web application while its getting uploaded and let user know that it needs to be fixed for the issues, so the vbscripting doesn't seem to be an option, but I will surely explore the LibreOffice python interface.