# Django displaying upload file content

Tags: django, file, upload

I have an application that loads different documents to the server, and allows users to read documents' content.
I am uploading the documents to the server, and then I try to read the courses by id, like:

```
 def view_course(request,id):
  u = Courses.objects.get(pk=id)
```

etc

But I don't find anywhere: how can I actually read the content of a /.doc/.pdf/.txt and display it on a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading plain text files is trivial, while PDF and Word processing is not. For the latter two you'll have to incorporate some external libraries.

- Text: [`f.read()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
- Word: [extracting text from MS word files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python)
- PDF: http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html

Comment: perfect, i'll study the docs, and publish my result.
thank you!