# Display contents of a file on django website

Tags: php, html, django

Im trying to display the contents of the text file with no luck. I have tried php which looked like an easy way to do it with no luck

base.html

```
{% load i18n static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
<head>
    <head lang=en>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div >
            <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: white; padding: 1.5rem;margin-bottom:i 100.5rem">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="/"><img src="{% static 'css/images/hadoop.png' %}"</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h2>Impala Query Metrics</h2>
                                    <hr class="my-2" href="{% url 'impala' %}">

                            </div>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$f = fopen("pathtofile/test.txt", "r");
// Read line from the text file and write the contents to the client
echo fgets($f);
fclose($f);
?>
```

I have also tried

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
readfile("pathtofile/test.txt");
?>
```

Also:

```
<?php
include("pathtofile/test.txt");
?>
```

Im not getting any errors nor seeing any results

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539849/how-to-echo-the-whole-content-of-an-html-file-in-php

Comment: @nullqube that did not work for me unfortunately

Comment: I'm curious why this is tagged with "php" *and* "django". Are you using PHP or Python?

Comment: @Goldentoa11 im using python. Should I still be able to use php in my base.html ? This is my first go at php

Comment: Ahh, okay. There are a few issues with that, which I'll try to point out in an answer. It may well still be doable, though I would question whether you should.

Comment: your code doesn't quite makes sense to me, as other mentioned django is python and if you want to use php the solution would be a dedicated php page for that matter that show the content of the file with any structure you want but fully in php. since you named your file .html I think the problem is it count as a broken html and neither django nor php can recognize it .

Comment: would you like me to give a snippet for that in python ?

Comment: @nullqube sure, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here; hopefully this provides some thoughts on where to go.

**First**, it appears that you want to run PHP code inside an HTML file, as the name of the file is `base.html`. The PHP interpreter is not configured (by default) to allow this, as it will only run files with the `php` extension. The fix for this would be to tell your web server to associate `html` files with the `application/x-httpd-php` mime type, so html files are ran through the php interpreter.

**Second**, I noticed the question is tagged with `django`, which is a Python framework. Do you have a PHP interpreter installed on the server? In order to execute PHP code, you'll need a PHP interpreter, which Python is not. To fix this, you would need to install a PHP interpreter (https://secure.php.net/ - right sidebar)

**Third**, should you really do this? Python and PHP both serve the same need, to provide server side processing to a web site. I would argue that you should use one or the other, but not both. Since you're already running Django, I would advise that you look for the Python-esque way of accomplishing a file include.

Comment: Here's an answer showing how to print a file in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256363/how-do-i-print-the-content-of-a-txt-file-in-python

Comment: Great. This makes much sense thank you for the explanation. I will try to find something with python

Answer (score 0):

assuming your file is text-file and you want the a html file that your data wrapped inside a div or so then :
I'm not a python fan but for python some links , not exactly same title but may good for beginning:

https://python-forum.io/Thread-read-text-file-using-python-and-display-its-output-to-html-using-django

[Django displaying upload file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983971/django-displaying-upload-file-content)

https://djangobook.com/generating-non-html-content/

or in php: 0.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div class="content-wrapper">
  <?php
   echo file_get_contents( "YOURFILE" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
  ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did u save it with an .php extension? and by the way how do address this file, by a link on some page or what?

Comment: i have alot more going on in base.html its a local file on linux. I dont think i can just rename base.html to php since its a template

Comment: no then you can not use php if it goes through Django it's python.