# Parsing a .doc (Word) file with a python script (Unix)

Tags: python, ms-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extracting text from MS word files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python)

I want to parse (in order to perform a search with an expression) a .doc file with a script in python. It runs on a unix machine.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Have you tried a simple search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at this project: [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx). 
After downloading the library, you can run `python example-extracttext.py docfile.docx textfile.txt | grep some-expression` in the shell. Surely you can also do more sophisticated search in python code when necessary.

The shortcoming of python-docx is it currently only supports ms-Word 2007/2008, if that concerns you, I recommend [antiword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiword), which supports Microsoft Word version 2, 6, 7, 97, 2000, 2002 and 2003. Actually I've been using that in my [vimrc](https://github.com/hzheng/vimconf) to be able to view ms-word files in VIM editor. Although it's not a python script, it can easily be invoked from Python.

Comment: would it work with .doc ?

Comment: As it's doc says, it can "Reads, queries and modifies Microsoft Word 2007/2008 docx files"

Comment: .doc is before 2K7, is I'm not mistaken

Comment: If you need read old-version ms-word files, try antiword.

Comment: Ok I will try with antiword

Answer (score 4):

You can use, [PyUno](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_samples)

Sample,

```
# HelloWorld python script for the scripting framework

def HelloWorldPython( ):
    """Prints the string 'Hello World(in Python)' into the current document"""
#get the doc from the scripting context which is made available to all scripts
    model = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
#get the XText interface
    text = model.Text
#create an XTextRange at the end of the document
    tRange = text.End
#and set the string
    tRange.String = "Hello World (in Python)"
    return None
```

Other, [PyUNO samples](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_samples)

Comment: From what i've read you need Open office installed ?

Comment: Yes you need to install OpenOffice or LibreOffice.

Comment: Can't do that. I did not mention it but the file is on the network

Comment: Actually you need to lib files. like this LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program: