# how to read output from .doc file in python?

Tags: python, ms-word, doc

I'm trying to read the text from a .doc file but it seems to only return some hex-looking info about the file.

Here's my IDE:

```
>>> output = open('letterlegal5.doc')
>>> output.read()
'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1'
```

What is this information and how do I convert the file to readable text?

Comment: We need more info. What platform? Do you need formatting? Take a look at this question nad its relatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python

Comment: I'll eventually need it on android. I'm running this on PC right now. It would be nice to retain the formatting. Thx for forwarding the link.