# How to parse doc files on a mac with python?

Tags: python

I've searched and found pywin32, but I can't seem to install it on the mac. Any suggestions? I want to parse doc files I have.

I'm specifically looking to parse DOC files, not DOCX.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python

Comment: to clarify though, isn't that thread about DOCX, not DOC?