# Where is the text stored in the docx object?

Tags: python, docx

Python has a library docx which is used to edit word documents. I read in the document using:

```
f = open('foobar.docx')
document = Document(f)
f.close()
```

From this page on git https://goo.gl/J9rncf, I realize the object is an instance of the Document class, which has a parent class ElementProxy. However, I'm unable to find a method which will output the text contained within the document object.

Comment: I'd start by looking at the `paragraphs` property.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979906/2623899.