# Read a Word file in shell unix

Tags: shell, .doc

Is it possible to read a .doc in order to obtain some informations in a shell unix ? 
is yes, how can we do this ?

Thanks for you answers! 
Regards,

Comment: Be specific; what information are you trying to read exactly?

Comment: There is a board with file name in a column and his directory in other column. I try to have file name and his directory to check if they exist.

Comment: So you don't care about the contents; you just want to check if the files exist? What does your input look like? [Edit] your question to show us.

Comment: You can read Word files with [tag:python] like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

There's "antiword".  That gives a plain text output of a Word doc.