# Loop Through Folder - Extract Heading 1 From Documents - Extract to New Document

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am trying to extract heading 1 from documents stored in a directory.

I am extremely new to python, so my experience is extremely limited.

My code below does not work, it has syntax and structural errors.

The code  returns an error document not defined.

```
import os

from docx import Document


#document = Document('C:\\Users\\Work\\Desktop\\Docs')

mydir ="C:\\Users\\Work\\Desktop\\Docs\\"
for arch in os.listdir(mydir):
archpath = os.path.join(mydir, arch)
with open(archpath) as f:

    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:

     if paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':

      print(paragraph.text)

    document.save = Document('headings.docx')
```

I have researched both on stack and on the internet, but I have not found anything that shows how to loop through documents in a folder.

Have I set the code up in the correct manner?
How can I loop through documents in a directory and extract the headings 1 to a new document.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of files that you can iterate over, you could use:

```
import os
os.chdir("path/to/files")
lists_of_files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

and then

```
for i in list_of_files:
    #extract heading from file i
```

For extracting the headers, you can use python's native [docx module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python). The link points to a SO answer where you can find a way of getting the entire data from the doc file. In this manner, you could get the heading. Haven't tried those methods though.