# Applying if else condition in Python depending on the file formats in folder

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder that contains many sub folders. First I want to check if there is any `".txt"` file. If yes I will do nothing regardless of any other file formats that exist in the same folder. If there is not, I will check whether there is `".csv"`, If yes I want to convert it/them to `".txt"`. Same also applies here, if I find `".csv"`, I don't care about other file formats

If there is no `".txt"` nor `".csv"`, probably it is `".doc"`. So, I want to convert it\them into `".txt"`

So the logic is: Find `".txt"`, if you find; continue and don't do anything with that folder. If you don't find  `".txt"`, look for `".csv"`, if you find `".csv"`, convert it\them to `".txt"`. Otherwise, look for `".doc"` and do the same.
How I could do that ?

Comment: Maybe try to reformat your problem from one big chunk of unstructured text to more digestible form. :)

Comment: Is it better now :) ?

Comment: You can search the subfolders with `glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)` with Python version >= 3.5, for older versions the recursive search via `**` works with the package `glob2` whch is available via `pip install glob2`.

Comment: For doc to txt conversion you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python

Csv to txt is rather straightforward. You just change extension since both are plain types.

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to find any directories in your desired folder. You could use `os.walk(directory)` which returns a generator of the folder and any sub-folders, as well as the files in it. Then you simply need to write some `if / elif` statements for what you want. Here's the first part of what you need.

```
from os import walk, rename, join


directory = './'
for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    if any([filename.endswith('.txt') for filename in filenames]):
        continue  # goes to the next iteration
    elif any([filename.endswith('.csv') for filename in filenames]):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.csv'):
                rename(join(folder, filename), join(folder, filename.replace('.txt')))  # rename changes a file's name, and join here is used for putting together the full path of the file
```

You still need to handle the `doc` files and I would suggest you to always make sure you understand what your code is doing. If you're not familiar with iteration or loops in general, check [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/loops/for-while-and-nested-loops-in-python). Note that the tutorial is for Python 2, apart from the parentheses in `print`, everything else stays the same.

Comment: So can I add another else if for the word documents ?

Comment: Can I use if file name ends with something else instead of csv ? how it would be in this case?

Comment: Yes, just replace the `.csv` with `.doc` in another `elif`. If you want to do exactly the same for both file extensions as you mentioned

Comment: and I want to create new files in the same directory I should add chdir to somewhere ?

Comment: My code doesn't change the working directory, just create the files to the directory you want, changing the directory is only necessary when you're doing a lot of tasks on that particular one.

Comment: It would have been really helpful if I could put new files to the folders that they have originated from

Comment: Because later on I will also merge them

Comment: The folder of each file is named under the variable `folder` under each `if` / `elif`. You can use that name to create any file. Still, did you read the tutorial I told you to? If not, you better do, I won't always be here to solve your problems.

Comment: I read it but tutorial that you send me is about if / else I asked you a question about changing the directory, but anyways, thank you