# Download file from URL and save it in a folder Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I've a lot of URL with file types `.docx` and `.pdf` I want to run a python script that downloads them from the URL and saves it in a folder. Here is what I've done for a single file I'll add them to a for loop:

```
response = requests.get('http://wbesite.com/Motivation-Letter.docx')
with open("my_file.docx", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

but the `my_file.docx` that it is saving is only 266 bytes and is corrupt but the URL is fine.

#### UPDATE:

Added this code and it works but I want to save it in a new folder.

```
import os
import shutil
import requests

def download_file(url, folder_name):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    path = os.path.join("/{}/{}".format(folder_name, local_filename))
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

    return local_filename
```

Comment: Please look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python) you might your answer here.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800385/how-to-download-ms-word-docx-file-in-python-with-raw-data-from-http-url/48811118

Comment: @RvdBerg it works but I am unable to figure out how to save them in a separate folder.

Comment: I think @IvanVinogradov answered your question.

Comment: Proper use of `os.path.join`: `path = os.path.join("/", folder_name, local_filename)`

Answer (score 36):

Try using [stream](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests) option:

```py
import os
import requests


def download(url: str, dest_folder: str):
    if not os.path.exists(dest_folder):
        os.makedirs(dest_folder)  # create folder if it does not exist

    filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "_")  # be careful with file names
    file_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, filename)

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.ok:
        print("saving to", os.path.abspath(file_path))
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()
                    os.fsync(f.fileno())
    else:  # HTTP status code 4XX/5XX
        print("Download failed: status code {}\n{}".format(r.status_code, r.text))


download("http://website.com/Motivation-Letter.docx", dest_folder="mydir")
```

Note that `mydir` in example above is the name of folder in **current working directory**. If `mydir` does not exist script will create it in current working directory and save file in it. Your user must have permissions to create directories and files in current working directory.

You can pass an absolute file path in `dest_folder`, but check permissions first.

P.S.: avoid asking multiple questions in one post

Comment: I'm using mac so in `file_path` when I write `r"\folder_name"` it creates a file name `\folder_name"`

Comment: So use os `os.path.join('whereever', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'go')` or pathlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html to correctly handle paths. Or add your own absolute path in your OS pathstyle of choice.

Comment: This answer just shows an example of handling file downloads with requests. Of course you should use os package to deal file file system)

Comment: @IvanVinogradovIn the update section of my question, when I run it I get `No such file or directory:`

Comment: You need to create a new folder and save the file in it?

Comment: This is what I'm doing creating a new folder `os.path.join("/{}/{}".format(folder_name, local_filename))` for which I get `No such file or directory:` and I've also tried `os.makedirs("/{}/{}".format(folder_name, local_filename))` and I get `Permission denied`

Comment: You get `permission denied` because your user is probably not allowed to create anything in root (`/`) directory

Comment: `filename` can be received from `re.findall("filename=(.+)",response.headers['Content-Disposition'])[0]` and it's more viable as there might be 301/302 redirections and initial url not to contain file name

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: this works as expected 

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
import urllib.request 
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: Worth noting that urlretrieve is a legacy function from Python 2 and might be deprecated at some point. It hasn't been thus far, but the documentation warns that it might.

Comment: I wonder why such commonly used and useful method gets deprecated without a suiteable replacement.

Comment: @JoergS a question for someone much smarter than me, but I totally agree with you :)