# Python docx - AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, docx

What I have as input: docx document raw bytes in byte64 format.
What I am trying to achieve: extract text from this document for further processing.
I tried to follow this answer: [extracting text from MS word files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python/1979906#1979906)

My code fragment:

```
base64_bytes = input.encode('utf-8')
decoded_data = base64.decodebytes(base64_bytes)
document = Document(decoded_data)
docText = '\n\n'.join([paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in document.paragraphs])
```

The `document = Document(decoded_data)` line gives me the following error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`
The `decoded_data` is in the following format: `b'PK\\x03\\x04\\x14\\x00\\x08\\x08\\x08\\x00\\x87@CP\\x00...`

How should I format the raw data to extract text from docx?

Comment: `input.encode('utf-8')`. Is this your actual code? Because this is trying to encode the function object `input` as UTF-8

Comment: 1) Your title says "`seek`", your question says "`code`". Which is it? 2) What exactly is `Document` and what kind of argument does it expect?

Comment: You say you are following the advise [Use the native Python docx module...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979906/2564301) and then -- you do *not* follow it. You do **not** need to encode, decode, or even explicitly load the file 'manually'.

Comment: @usr2564301 they only diverge where they have to, their input is in-memory base64 content rather than a file on disk.

Answer (score 16):

From the official documentation, emphasis mine:

> docx.Document(docx=None)
>
> Return a Document object loaded from docx, where **docx can be either a path to a .docx file (a string) or a file-like object**. If docx is missing or None, the built-in default document “template” is loaded.

So if you provide a string or string-like parameter it is interpreted as the path to a docx file. To provide the contents from memory, you need to pass in a file-like object aka a BytesIO instance (the entire point of StringIO and BytesIO being to "convert" strings and bytes to file-like objects):

```py
document = Document(io.BytesIO(decoded_data))
```

side-note: you probably want to remove the `.encode` call in the list comprehension, in Python 3 text (str) and bytes (bytes) are not compatible at all, so the line is going to blow up when you try to concatenate bytes (encoded text) with textual separators.

Comment: Doing this, I get an `Exception: BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`. I've tried creating a ZipFile class instance with the BytesIO(decoded_data) object but I get a different error doing so. Any thoughts?

Comment: That your file is not an actual docx? Possibly a "legacy" doc file? A docx is a zipfile, so internally `docx.Document` will open the zipfile and start parsing its content.

Comment: That's the tough part here is that I turned a known .docx file into base64 to test passing it via a JSON request body. Ingesting the base64 string, decoding it into a BytesIO instance is result in that error. Womp womp. I think I'll probably post a question. Thanks for the response!