# How does one write Python code that merges 2 files created using wkhtmltopdf into 1 pdf file using pypdf2

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf, pypdf

I have an application with the back-end written in Python that converts html files to pdf files. To do this it implements wkhtmltopdf (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It currently works perfectly for creating a single PDF file from an html file and outputs that to the user.

However, I need to be able to create multiple *separate* PDF files and then merge the files together into a single PDF.

I have been trying to do this using Pypdf2 with the PdfFileMerger() function (https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html) and haven't been able to do it. I keep getting `'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`

Here is my current code:

```
def multi_test_sheet(request, equipment_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "jobs/login.html", {"message": None})
    from io import BytesIO
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "jobs/login.html", {"message": None})
    equipment = Equipment.objects.filter(pk=equipment_id).first()
    if not job:
        raise Http404("test sheet error. Error code: get job failed")
    pdf_write = PdfFileWriter()
    user_properties=UserProperties.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = {
        "equipment": equipment,
        "job": equipment.equipments,
        "test_sheet": equipment.sheet_eq,
        "user_properties": user_properties,
        "now": datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y %H:%M"),
        "now_date": datetime.now().date()
    }
    
    html_sheet = render_to_string('jobs/test_sheet_gear1.html', context)
    html_sheet2 = render_to_string('jobs/test_sheet_gear2.html', context)
    pdf_content1 = pdfkit.from_string(html_sheet, None) 
    pdf_content2 = pdfkit.from_string(html_sheet2, None) 
    pdfadder = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    pdfadder.append(pdf_content1)
    pdfadder.append(pdf_content2)
    pdf_adder.write("combined_sheets.pdf")

    response = HttpResponse(pdf_adder, content_type="application/pdf")
    
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"filename={equipment.site_id}.pdf"

    return response
```

Comment: Somewhere a file-like object is expected but a bytes object is found. Investigate the traceback that comes along with the error message to find out where it comes from.

Comment: What are you using `BytesIO` for?

Comment: What are you using `pdf_write` for?

Comment: I found a stackoverflow article that indicated something about using BytesIO but it didn't work so I removed it but forgot to remove the variables. Article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093581/python-docx-attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-seek

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by hiring someone. The problem was that the objects being passed into the PyPDF2 function called `PdfFileMerger()` were not being recognized as pdf objects.

To resolve that, save the files (I place them in a folder called interim) using the second argument from the `pdfkit.from_string()` function, then assign the newly created files to independent variables using open() function, and finally proceed with the merging function by merging those variables.

```
def multi_test_sheet(request, equipment_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "jobs/login.html", {"message": None})
    from io import BytesIO
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "jobs/login.html", {"message": None})
    equipment = Equipment.objects.filter(pk=equipment_id).first()
    if not job:
        raise Http404("test sheet error. Error code: get job failed")
    page_quantity = 2 #temporary value for a property that will be added to either equipment or test sheet model
    pdf_file_object = BytesIO()
    stream = BytesIO()
    pdf_write = PdfFileWriter()
    user_properties=UserProperties.objects.get(user=request.user)
    today = datetime.now()
    now=today.strftime("%b-%d-%Y %H:%M")
    now_date = today.date()
    context = {
        "equipment": equipment,
        "job": equipment.equipments,
        "test_sheet": equipment.sheet_eq,
        "user_properties": user_properties,
        "now": now,
        "now_date": now_date
    }
    
    html_sheet = render_to_string('jobs/test_sheet_gear1.html', context)
    html_sheet2 = render_to_string('jobs/test_sheet_gear2.html', context)
    pdf_content1 = pdfkit.from_string(html_sheet, 'interm/test_sheet_gear1.pdf') 
    pdf_content2 = pdfkit.from_string(html_sheet2, 'interm/test_sheet_gear2.pdf')     
    pdfadder = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    pdf1_v=PdfFileReader(open('interm/test_sheet_gear1.pdf', 'rb'))
    pdf2_v=PdfFileReader(open('interm/test_sheet_gear2.pdf', 'rb'))
    pdfadder.append(pdf1_v, import_bookmarks=False)
    pdfadder.append(pdf2_v, import_bookmarks=False)
    pdfadder.write('interm/'+str(user_properties.pk)+'combined_sheets.pdf')
    output_file = open('interm/combined_sheets.pdf', 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(output_file, content_type="application/pdf")
    
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"filename={equipment.site_id}.pdf"


    return response
```